# Remove repetitive sections from Javascript (DRY)

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript that switches the different views. All works fine however it is extremely repetitive. I would like to clean it up but not to sure how I would go about it.

```
function switchView () {

var viewContainer = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
var tileBtn       = document.getElementById('tile-btn');
var listBtn       = document.getElementById('list-btn');
var swipeBtn      = document.getElementById('swipe-btn');


tileBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){

if (viewContainer.classList.contains('list-view') || 
  viewContainer.classList.contains('swipe-view') ) {
   e.preventDefault();
  viewContainer.classList.remove('list-view');
  viewContainer.classList.remove('swipe-view');
  viewContainer.classList.add('tile-view');
}
});

listBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){

if (viewContainer.classList.contains('tile-view') || 
 viewContainer.classList.contains('swipe-view') ) {
   e.preventDefault();
    viewContainer.classList.remove('tile-view');
    viewContainer.classList.remove('swipe-view');
    viewContainer.classList.add('list-view');
}
});

swipeBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){

if (viewContainer.classList.contains('list-view') || 
viewContainer.classList.contains('tile-view') ) {
   e.preventDefault();
    viewContainer.classList.remove('list-view');
    viewContainer.classList.remove('tile-view');
    viewContainer.classList.add('swipe-view');
}
});

};

switchView();
```

Comment: If you have working code, and you want to get it reviewed for optimization or performance, codereview is the best place. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The 'if' clause is unnecessary -- at worst, you'd be removing a class and then adding it back again, which is harmless -- so just remove it.  After that, the functions are identical except for the classname to be added, so combine them into a single function with a parameter for that classname.

Comment: (That said, yeah, @RaviChandra is correct; codereview is a more appropriate place for this question)

Comment: Thanks @RaviChandra and Daniel i will post it there